# Change Bootstrap carousel controls background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Good day!

I am using the Bootstrap carousel on a project and I wanted to change the background color of the items and controls. By changing the background property of the CSS the results are perfect in Chrome, IE and Opera, but it does not work well in Firefox and in mobile browsers.

```
background : linear-gradient(to left, #f8f8f8 0%, transparent 100%);
```

My guess is that the problem is that they fail to render the 'transparent' color, because if I change it to anything else, it works fine (with that color). But I need it to be transparent because the background of the items is also a gradient and it wouldn't look right otherwise. My code also includes all the needed vendor prefixes.

[image]

This is how it looks (on Firefox and mobile it maintains its original 'dark-ish' color; it looks even worse when I hover it)

Thank you very much for your help!
Have a nice day!

EDIT: Someone requested that I add a fiddle - if you run it in Chrome and in Firefox, you will get different results for the color (even IE11 gets it right this time); http://jsfiddle.net/3UN3E/1/

Comment: did you prefix (`-moz, -webkit, etc`) the `linear-gradient`? You'd also have to change the CSS for the `:hover` background gradient as well.

Comment: Yes, I have included all the vendor prefixes. The :hover only changes the opacity, not the color.

Comment: please add html in a fiddle!